# Mysqli not finding row

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to let a user login here is my login script atm im just checking if the username exists but for some reason its not finding any records even though the user name is right

```
<?php if(isset($_POST)){ 
print_r($_POST);

    //Variables from the table 
    $usernamelogin = $_POST['usernamelogin']; 
    $passwordlogin = $_POST['passwordlogin']; 
    //Prevent MySQL Injections 
    $usernamelogin = stripslashes($usernamelogin); 
    $passwordlogin = stripslashes($passwordlogin); 

    $usernamelogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $usernamelogin); 
    $passwordlogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $passwordlogin); 

    $loginquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM reg_users WHERE user ='$usernamelogin' AND authorised ='1'") or die("Can not query DB."); 
    $logincount = mysqli_num_rows($loginquery);

    if($logincount == 1){
        echo "user exists";
    } else { 
        echo "User doesnt exist"; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

my table is called reg_users and user is the column the username goes into. i am doing the same thing on register and that works

Any ideas guys?

table is

```
 `reg_users` (
 `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `surname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `authorised` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `activationcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And the sqlfiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b92c8/2)

Here is the config.php which is called in the header of the page

```
<?php //Information to connect to your MySQL Server AND DB 
$hostdb    = "localhost"; 
$userdb = "test_nathan"; 
$passworddb = "xxxxx"; 
$db       = "test_nathan"; 

//Connect to MySQL Server 
$con = mysqli_connect($hostdb,$userdb,$passworddb,$db) or die ("could not connect"); 

session_save_path('../login/sessions');
require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

Comment: could you put the table structure also ? is the connection open ?

Comment: What is your problem? Does it always show the username is taken, or does it never show? Or does your PHP throws errors?

Comment: Why don't you check if user and password are correct instead of user and authorized?Also check, don't you have a duplicate entry of user inside the table?one more thing, I do not see $con inside your php block.

Comment: shows no errors just doesnt find the field the database connection is called in the header which is called at the top of the page i will show db structure now

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem guys for some reason when i was storing the variables on escaping the string there was spaces attached to the variable. thanks for the help guys.